# Force hibernate to NOT retrieve full object

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

i am given a task at work where I have to use hibernate and some classes which are mapped to views. The task says, that i should create a select on one view which does not return a complete object of the class, but an object with just some attributes of the class initialized. i first thought about creating a constructor which only gets these fields as parameter, but I can't find any solution on the web, which holds both possibilities open (parts of the class and full class). Any suggestion is welcome. If you need any code or further explanation, ask for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create jpql query or use criteria api to select attributes you want.

JPQL tutorial is http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbtg.html

Criteria is http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjivm.html

Comment: i am actually using criteria, but i can't find the part, where i only select given attributes. can you show me an example? or is it the part with `root.get(attributes)` within the select?

Comment: and do you have any idea, how i can fetch a max of 1000 records, but check if the result would be bigger than 1000? currently i use `setMaxResults()`

Comment: root.get(attributes) is the only way I know so far

Comment: you may like to check Projections api to do what you want using criteria.

Comment: @JaySmith. how you can use criteria to fetch the data from view?

Comment: @Vaibs instead of mapping the object to a table, you map it to the view. then it just works like you mapped it to a table

Comment: @XtremeBaumer I need to try this.

Comment: @Vaibs its good if you don't want to change any data, but view them

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code.

You can use native sql query in createQuery() and fetch the parameter which you need only then you can transform your result in appropriate class

```
Query query =  ((SQLQuery) getSession().createSQLQuery(
                "select First_name,Last_name,email_id,.. from view_name  where customer_id=:customer_id").
                setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(CustomerProfile.class))).             
                setParameter("customer_id", cutsomer_id)
                ;       
        List<CustomerProfile> list = query.list();
```

Need to to Create   CustomerProfile.class with getter and setter.

Comment: i think this negates the work with hibernate a bit because of the native sql

Comment: Your question states that , you want to fetch data from view.AFAIK you can not create the primary key on fields of view. And Hibernate requires that model should have primary key.I think the only way to fetch data from view is using native sql in hibernate.

Comment: this is where you are wrong. if a view exists, you can simply specify the "table" annotation to the view instead. this works perfectly fine. i am already doing it with a whole abject and now also with just parts of the object